# logstash keeps placing just 1 entry in my index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have the following logstash conf file:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC DRIVER 6.2 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_6.2\enu\mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://TST-DBS-20;user=Elasticsearch;password=elastic123;"
    jdbc_user => "Elasticsearch"
    statement => "SELECT NewsID, HeadLine, BodyText, DateSubmitted, Approved, NULLIF(UserName,'') as UserName, NULLIF(Type,'') as NewsType, NULLIF(Caption,'') as caption, NULLIF(Author,'') as Author, NULLIF(Contact,'') as Contact, NULLIF(StaffID,'') as StaffID, SocialClubRegionID, DateCreated, CreatedBy, LastModifiedDate, ModifiedBy
FROM [News].[dbo].[News]"
  }
}
filter {
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["tst-sch-20:9200"]
    index => "newsindex"
    document_id => "%{id}"
    user => "elastic"
    password => elastic123
  }
  stdout { codec => json }
}
```

and I've created the following index:

```
put newsindex
{
  "settings" : {
    "number_of_shards":3,
    "number_of_replicas":2
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "news": {
      "properties": {
        "NewsId": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "newstype": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "bodytext": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After running the above script, there's no entry in the logstash log files to suggest anything went wrong. If I run the SQL command directly in SQL,then strangely enough, the single entry in the index is the last entry of my select statement, so it's almost as if the script is inserting then overwriting such that I end up with a single record.

Comment: You are aware of this right? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#_predefined_parameters

Comment: I am aware of these. In my original test, I didn't use either of these and I used as per the above but against a test DB and all worked. I've added the `tracking_column` below my statement, and this hasn't made any difference.

Comment: interesting. I now added `use_column_value` and Bang index populated with the expected amount of records. the count from the query against the db matches they count shown in kibana. On my original test DB I created a table with a number of columns and populated the table with 500 records. I wrote my .conf file in the format above and all worked. The only difference here is that I'm running the latest release of logstash, so maybe they have tightened up on it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `_id` field of the record loaded into Elasticsearch, you'll see it is `%{id}` because your query does not have an `id` field.  You'll want to change to `document_id => "%{newsid}"` or whatever makes sense based on your query.

Comment: I noticed that and have changed the document_id to be as per your example. I still only receive the last record in the index. I destroyed and re-created the index before running again to ensure I was running clean, but it made no difference.

Comment: what does the event that's loaded look like?  Does it have a `newsid` field or is it `NewsID` -- the default looks like it'd lowercase the field names unless you set `lowercase_column_names`

Comment: The DB is declared as NewsID, but looking via Kibana shows newsid

Comment: updated my answer to `%{newsid}` -- you can change the casing behavior by changing the `lowercase_column_names` setting per the docs.